# Range of getting values from JSOUP

Tags: java, range, jsoup

I have method like this:

```
return String.valueOf(doc.select("a[href]").get(1).text())
```

With this method i gets 2 value from 15 existing.

I need to get values 7, 8, 9, 10. How i can to get this?

Comment: You need to provide more code. What if the values are blank etc.? What source HTML are you parsing, and have you checked what the `get()`-method does?

Answer (score 1):

If you need links from 7th to 10th, you can write:

```
  int i = 0;
  for (Element e : doc.select("a[href]"))
  {
    i++;
    if (i>=7)
      System.out.println(e.text());
    if (i==10)
      break;
  }
```

Considering an input document with 15 html <a> elements:

```
 <a href="X1">link1</a>
 <a href="X2">link2</a>
 <a href="X3">link3</a>
 <a href="X4">link4</a>
 <a href="X5">link5</a>
 <a href="X6">link6</a>
 <a href="X7">link7</a>
 <a href="X8">link8</a>
 <a href="X9">link9</a>
 <a href="X10">link10</a>
 <a href="X11">link11</a>
 <a href="X12">link12</a>
 <a href="X13">link13</a>
 <a href="X14">link14</a>
 <a href="X15">link15</a>
```

The output result is:

```
link7
link8
link9
link10
```